# Store serial communication's data from Arduino to Java using RXTX library

Tags: java, serialization, arduino, rxtx

I have a problem with RXTX library and Arduino, I'm trying to store a variable obtained from Arduino serial output into a variable that it's declared in my Java code and then use it to execute some actions. This is a part of code that I use to read the serial output from Arduino.

Now the question is, how can I store that data starting from this code?

I need to store data obtained from an ultrasonic sensor and let it show to my Java GUI.

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
  if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
    try {
      byte singleData = (byte)input.read();
      if (singleData != NEW_LINE_ASCII) {
        logText = new String(new byte[] { singleData });
        finestra.logArea.append(logText);
      } else {
        finestra.logArea.append("\n");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      logText = "Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")";
      finestra.logArea.setForeground(Color.red);
      finestra.logArea.append(logText + "\n");
    }
  }
```

This part of code is just to read all that came from the serial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to use Javino middleware instead of RxTx?

Your Java code will be like that:

```
Javino j = new Javino();
String receivedMessage = new String();
if (j.requestData("COM3","hi")) 
   receivedMessage = j.getData();
```

And your Arduino code (inside main loop):

```
if(javino.availablemsg()){
    msg = javino.getmsg();
}

if (msg=="hi) {
    javino.sendmsg("Your Value");
}

msg = "";
```

And so it is.